# Do I need a Mutex when using a circular buffer and the Producer / Consumer design pattern

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I have two threads that communicate via a circular buffer.

```
/* Initialize not_full semaphore to a count of BUFFER_SIZE */
sem_init(&not_full_semaphore, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
/* Initialize not_empty semaphore to a count of 0 */
sem_init(&not_empty_semaphore, 0, 0);

void producer_thread (void) {
    int item
    int head = 0;

    while(true) {
        item = produce_item();

        sem_wait(&not_full_semaphore);
        mutex_lock(&circular_buffer_mutex);
        /* Insert item into the buffer */
        circular_buffer[head] = item;
        /* Increment head offset and wrap if necessary */
        head = (head == BUFFER_SIZE - 1) ? 0 : head + 1;
        mutex_unlock(&circular_buffer_mutex);
        sem_post(&not_empty_semaphore);
    }
}

void consumer_thread (void){
    int item;
    int tail = 0;

    while(true) {
        sem_wait(&not_empty_semaphore);
        mutex_lock(&circular_buffer_mutex);
        /* Remove item from the buffer */
        item = circular_buffer[tail];
        /* Increment tail offset and wrap if necessary */
        tail = (tail == BUFFER_SIZE - 1) ? 0 : tail + 1;
        mutex_unlock(&circular_buffer_mutex);
        sem_post(&not_full_semaphore);
        consume_item(item);
    }
```

My Question is do I really need the mutex?  It would appear to me that there is no chance that the producer and consumer would ever be accessing the same memory at the same time.  The consumer won't read until the producer is done writing and has signaled it via the not_empty semaphore.  And the producer will be prevented from wrapping around and writing again by the not_full semaphore.  So it doesn't appear to me that I need the mutex, but all the examples that I have found make use of it.

Comment: In the specific case of only one producer and only one consumer, and given a queue structure with head index only accesed by producer and tail only by consumer, you can get away without the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

> My Question is do I really need the mutex?

Yes, you do.

Without the mutex, since you initialize your `not_full_semaphore` to a value that's potentially greater than one, in this code:

```
while(true) {
    item = produce_item();

    sem_wait(&not_full_semaphore);

    // can reach here while the consumer thread is
    // accessing the circular buffer

    // but this mutex prevents both threads from
    // accessing the circular buffer simultaneously
    mutex_lock(&circular_buffer_mutex);
```

your producer thread won't wait for the consumer thread to be done before producing the next item.

> And the producer will be prevented from wrapping around and writing again by the not_full semaphore.

That's not correct.  The producer thread won't have to wait for the consumer thread if the `not_full_semaphore` is initialized to a value greater than one.

Comment: Say there's 8 spaces in the buffer. Then not_full is initialized to 8 and not_empty is initialized to 0. Each space in the buffer is clearly set aside for one thread or the other (with an empty buffer, all to producer). Each thread turns over a space to the other only when it's done with it. If there's a problem with the two threads running concurrently, you haven't explained what it is.

Comment: But the producer thread should be able to produce as many items as there are spaces in the circular buffer.  Once it is full the producer thread will be prevented from producing any more until the consumer thread has consumed some.
My point is that as long as they are not accessing the same location in the circular buffer, what is the harm in letting them both access it?

Comment: @ACRL you are correct in concluding that the semaphores manage the queue count just fine on their own.  The mutex is there to prevent corruption when performing operations on the queue, eg: '/* Increment tail offset and wrap if necessary */'  Think about it - with several producer and consumer threads, and the queue half-full, there could be many threads trying to manipulate the queue indices in parallel, resulting in TOCTTOU.... 'incidents'